# How to properly use generics with ngrx actions

Tags: typescript, ngrx

I'm working on a Angular 7 app that uses the NGRX store. We have a lot of entities, and almost each one has a dedicated list view. I wanted to try out generics with NGRX store, so I would not need to write almost identical selectors, actions, reducers etc. I started with actions and created a function that would return me a set of them, but I cannot get it to work.

```
    // For type safety
    enum AddTypeNames {
      ADD_REQUEST = 'AddRequestAction',
      ADD_SUCCESS = 'AddSuccessAction',
      ADD_FAILURE = 'AddFailureAction',
    }
    // Creates an object literal with a string key and Action as the value
    function createAddActions<T>(featureName: string): { [key in AddTypeNames]: Action } {
      class AddRequestAction implements Action {
        readonly type = `[${featureName}] Add request`;
        constructor(payload: { entity: T }) { }
      }
      class AddSuccessAction implements Action {
        readonly type =  `[${featureName}] Add success`;
        constructor(payload: { entity: T }) { }
      }
      class AddFailureAction implements Action {
        readonly type =  `[${featureName}] Add error`;
        constructor(payload: { error: HttpErrorResponse }) { }
      }
      return {
        AddRequestAction,
        AddSuccessAction,
        AddFailureAction,
      };
    }
```

But it's showing an error in the editor saying:

```
(property) AddRequestAction: Action
Property 'type' is missing in type 'typeof AddRequestAction' but required in type 'Action'.ts(2741)
```

I've no idea what this error really means, as clearly I do have the type in the class... Am I even doing this the right way? What would I need to do to create actions with generic types? Is it actually considered a good practice to use generics as much as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Compilation error existing because you declared that `createAddActions` will return dict od Action `{ [key in AddTypeNames]: Action }`. But this syntax means object of instances of class Action, not a classes.

So, you told TS that your return object values contains attribute 'type', your classes has not static attribute `type`.

If you want to declare that result of functions is object with classes (not instances of it use this syntax: `{ new (...args): Action }`.

So:

```js
function createAddActions<T>(featureName: string): { [key in AddTypeNames]: { new (...args): Action } } {
```

will not throws compilation error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20%2F%2F%20For%20type%20safety%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Action%20%7B%20type%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20enum%20AddTypeNames%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ADD_REQUEST%20%3D%20'AddRequestAction'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ADD_SUCCESS%20%3D%20'AddSuccessAction'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ADD_FAILURE%20%3D%20'AddFailureAction'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Creates%20an%20object%20literal%20with%20a%20string%20key%20and%20Action%20as%20the%20value%0D%0Afunction%20createAddActions%3CT%3E(featureName%3A%20string)%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20AddTypeNames%5D%3A%20%7B%20new%20(...args)%3A%20Action%20%7D%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20class%20AddRequestAction%20implements%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20readonly%20type%20%3D%20%60%5B%24%7BfeatureName%7D%5D%20Add%20request%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(payload%3A%20%7B%20entity%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20class%20AddSuccessAction%20implements%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20readonly%20type%20%3D%20%20%60%5B%24%7BfeatureName%7D%5D%20Add%20success%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(payload%3A%20%7B%20entity%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20class%20AddFailureAction%20implements%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20readonly%20type%20%3D%20%20%60%5B%24%7BfeatureName%7D%5D%20Add%20error%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(payload%3A%20%7B%20error%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AddRequestAction%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AddSuccessAction%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AddFailureAction%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out. So now I don't have compiler errors, but I cannot use these actions like normal ones with effects, as I cannot write:
    const addActions = createAddActions('user');
    type AddUserTypes = addActions.AddRequestAction | addActions.AddSuccessAction | addActions.AddFailureAction;    
    ...
    ofType<addActionTypes.AddRequestAction>(...)
    ...

I guess it's because  "new (...args: any[]) => Action". Something tells me that I ain't doing this right way at all...

Comment: I',m guess you recieved `Cannot find namespace 'addActions'.` error. That's because you used object as type definition in ` type AddUserTypes = addActions.AddRequestAction`. If you want to use type of `addActions.AddRequestAction` for this definition you have to add `typeof` keyword. So final code will looks like this `type AddUserTypes = typeof addActions.AddRequestAction | typeof addActions.AddSuccessAction;`